# Encoding problems when migrating Apache Velocity

Tags: encoding, migration, velocity, velocity-tools

I have been using Apache Velocity for years in my Tomcat web platform.

I was under very old versions: velocity-1.6.4 and velocity-tools-1.4
and I recently decided to migrate my whole platform and to use **velocity-engine 2.3** and **velocity-tools 3.1**

Since I have around 15 web applications, the process was a bit long but quite straightforward. Unfortunately, I have some rendering problems, specially :

- The Euro sign € is not rendered properly.
- When the web page loads external scripts with labels, (accents in French, special characters) they seem to be ANSI characters.

Here is the kind of stuff I get:

Accents, dollar, punctuation: àèù, $, ! ?,

**Euro sign: ?**

**From external js : Ã©Ã Ã¨Ã¹ $#**#!?â‚¬

**The same template, with same tomcat configuration, but with the very old versions of velocity displays perfectly**. If plain HTML, it also works (the Connectors in Tomcat config file server.xml precise UTF-8).

Every thing is in UTF-8.
The velocityservlet is a basic "velocity servlet", as simple as possible.
With the last versions of Velocity, the velocity properties config file only contains:

**resource.loaders = webapp**

**resource.loader.webapp.class = org.apache.velocity.tools.view.WebappResourceLoader**

**resource.loader.webapp.path = /WEB-INF/templates/**

I have checked by code inside the servlet that the property getVelocityProperty(RuntimeConstants.INPUT_ENCODING, RuntimeConstants.ENCODING_DEFAULT) was UTF-8.

After nights and days on the problem, I feel quite desperate!
Thank you for your help.

Comment: You face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (*example in Python for its universal intelligibility*): `print( '€éàèù'.encode( 'utf-8').decode( 'cp1252'))` returns `â‚¬Ã©Ã Ã¨Ã¹`

Comment: Yes, thank you, but the javascript file is UTF-8 encoded and everything is UTF-8 and if I take old version of Velocity, it is fine.

Comment: And if I copy the velocity template in an HTML file, it is perfect. Something must be wrong with my usage of this particular version of Velocity.

Comment: Which kind of view servlet are you using? Where do you set the encoding of the response?

Answer (score 1):

I found my problem!
My "Charset filter" was not filtering "response" but only request.
However, I am puzzled by the code of the method initRequest of class VelocityViewServlet:

protected void initRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException
{
try
{
request.setCharacterEncoding(getVelocityProperty(RuntimeConstants.INPUT_ENCODING, RuntimeConstants.ENCODING_DEFAULT));

```
    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee)
    {
        error(request, response, uee);
        throw uee;
    }
}
```

I wonder why Velocity does not apply the setCharacterEncoding on the response. And only on the request.
I would have added the response.setCharacterEncoding line, intuitively:
response.setCharacterEncoding(getVelocityProperty(RuntimeConstants.INPUT_ENCODING, RuntimeConstants.ENCODING_DEFAULT));

In the old version of Velocity, we had 2 config parameters:
input.encoding=UTF-8
output.encoding=UTF-8

And now, only one:
resource.default_encoding=UTF-8
But it should be applied to both request and response.
Am I missing a point?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same trouble today, finally I override the protected setContentType method in my VeloServlet class and the problem was solved:

```
public class MyVeloServlet extends VelocityViewServlet {

...

    @Override
    protected void setContentType(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
    }
}
```

It is possible to reach this result with a configuration key in velocity.properties:

```
default.contentType=text/html; charset=UTF-8
```